# browser print preview does not have my site logo

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, preview, print-preview

On my website. If I do a print preview (with IE9 for example) How does it come that I don't have my site logo in the print preview?

Please do not attack if this question already asked (i didn't find any)

Thanks for reply

Comment: Are there ***any*** images in the print preview?

Comment: Yes, there are, but is with the html tag `<img/>`, Other one that doesnt show up is done with css (background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers don't print background colors and images by default because it's typically a waste of ink (e.g. printing white text on a black background).

If your logo is semantically significant, use an `<img>` tag.